# WPF Namespace confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have two clrnamespaces that I need to access from a WPF Window, which have a clash in names

```
xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:Namespace1.Namespace2.Namespace3.Namespace4;assembly="
xmlns:ns2="clr-namespace:Namespace2;assembly=Namespace2"
```

When I go to use anything from Namespace2 such as

```
<Canvas>
  <ns2:MyControl ... />
</Canvas>
```

I get the following compile error

```
The type or namespace name 'MyControl' does not exist in the namespace 'Namespace1.Namespace2' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I know the naming of the namespaces aren't very good, but changing the former would require moving away from the structure used elsewhere in the system and changing the latter would require changes to other parts of the system.

Does anyone have any suggestions for ways round this?

Comment: In the `xmlns:ns1` line, are you actually omitting the name of the assembly, or is it just a typo here on SO?

Comment: I'm actually omitting the name. It is in the same assembly. I know I can leave this out, but I feel it is more explicit to leave it in.

Comment: @jamesj: According to [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/648fec51-f00e-45ca-85e7-04c80e06ba33), it is not even always possible to leave it out.

Comment: can you please show actual code. Up there are mistakes that can be either typeing mistake or may be the exact problem.

Comment: @jamesj: I'd however like to know whether `xmlns:ns2` is actually declared without `clr-namespace:` in front of the namespace name.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper sorry fixed in example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a solution using "xmlns:" then you could consider using `XmlnsDefinition` to map multiple clrnamespaces into an XML namespace identified by a URI, and then use that URI to refer to the set of clr namespaces.

Put an `XmlnsDefinition` into the `AssemblyInfo.cs` of each assembly that contains those CLR types you want to group.

```
[XmlnsDefinition("http://www.mycompany.com/appname", "Namespace1.Namespace2.Namespace3.Namespace4")]

[XmlnsDefinition("http://www.mycompany.com/appname", "Namespace2")]
```

- http://www.global-webnet.net/blogengine/post/2010/06/20/WPF-assembly-XmlnsDefinition-identify-types-for-XAML-usage.aspx

Then in your XAML you can do:

```
xmlns:ns="http://www.mycompany.com/appname"
```

and it should then allow you to access the types using a common prefix.

---

On the otherhand maybe you forgot to add a reference to the Namespace2 DLL to your project?

If none of the above works, can you describe your project structure a bit more e.g. can you show the MyControl code...where it lives...and also show the namespace statements of the code.